# Add child to parent list inside MVC parent edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an edit page for a `ComicPanel` which contains a list of `ComicPanelText`.

I want to add a new ComicPanelText, so I need an 'Add' button, but the submit button goes to my EditController.  How can I add a new submit button determine which button was pressed in the controller?

> Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ComicPanelText.cshtml

```
@model ComicNet.Models.ComicPanelText

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ComicPanelTextId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ComicText)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

> Views/ComicPanels/Edit.cshtml

```
@model ComicNet.Models.ComicPanel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PanelNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PanelNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img src='@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Url)' width="200" height="200" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Width)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Width)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Height)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Height)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageUpload)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
            </td>
        </tr>

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ComicPanelTexts)

    </table>


    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileName)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComicPanelId)
    </div>





    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>





<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

> ComicPanelsController.cs

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ComicPanel comicPanel)
        {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can pass the button name into the Controller

```
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="addText" value="Add" />



   public ActionResult Edit(ComicPanel comicPanel, string submit)
    {
        if(submit == "Add")
        {
            var newComicPanelText = new ComicPanelText();
            comicPanel.ComicPanelTexts.Add(newComicPanelText);
            db.Entry(newComicPanelText).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.Entry(comicPanel).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(comicPanel);
        }
```